# Which Star Trek episodes/films feature the everyday struggles of the physically disabled?

Tags: star-trek

I would like to know which Star Trek episodes/films feature a character struggling with a physical disability (i.e. a limitation on a person's physical functioning, mobility, dexterity or stamina). Episodes just showing Geordi wearing his VISOR don't count.

Comment: Do traumatic injuries count as disabilities?

Comment: I think a traumatic injury does not count in an of itself, but can lead to a situation where someone struggles with a physical disability. TNG - Ethics comes to mind as an example of an episode where a character (Worf) struggles with a physical disability (complete paralysis) as a result of a traumatic injury (a barrel falling on him in the cargo bay, if I remember correctly).

Comment: Does [deafness](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Loud_As_A_Whisper_(episode)) count as a physical disability?

Comment: I would argue in the affirmative on the ground that deafness can adversely effect a person's physical functioning. I'm reminded of Riva in the TNG episode Loud as a Whisper.

Comment: From Q's point of view, they *all* do.

Comment: Don't forget Picard's dementia-enduring syndrome in All Good Things. And Picard has an artificial heart I believe (can't remember which Q episode it's in)

Comment: @iMerchant The "Q" episode is [Tapestry](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Tapestry_(episode)), although his artificial heart also shows up in [Samaritan Snare](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Samaritan_Snare_(episode))

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In [TOS: "The Menagerie"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Menagerie,_Part_I_(episode)), Christopher Pike uses a special life support chair following his exposure to delta radiation. In the 2009 movie, he's seen using a wheelchair after being tortured by Nero.

[image: on the left, pike in a wheelchair. on the right, pike encased in a life-support chair]

In [TOS: "Is There in Truth No Beauty?"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Is_There_in_Truth_No_Beauty%3F_(episode)), Dr. Miranda Jones wears a "sensor web" dress to compensate for having been born blind. She is ashamed of her disability and hides it from the crew.

[image: jones in a shiny "sensor web" dress]

In [Wrath of Khan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_II:_The_Wrath_of_Khan), Admiral Kirk is forced to wear eyeglasses due to deteriorating eyesight, since he is allergic to a common sight-restoring drug. He is embarrassed by his age.

[image: Kirk staring at his glasses in disapproval]

In [TNG: "Too Short a Season"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Too_Short_a_Season_(episode)), Admiral Jameson uses a support chair due to the effects of Iverson's disease. In response to his deterioration, he subjects himself to a dangerous rejuvenation therapy.

[image: Jameson sitting inside a support "chair"]

In [TNG: "Ethics"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ethics_(episode)), Worf is paralyzed following a traumatic spinal injury. He wishes to commit suicide since he can no longer be a warrior.

[image: Worf on the floor, unable to walk]

In [DS9: "It's Only a Paper Moon"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/It%27s_Only_a_Paper_Moon_(episode)), Nog struggles to adapt to an artificial leg that he received after losing his original leg in combat. His main struggle is psychological (PTSD, another disability), but he is seen complaining of pain and using a cane to walk.

[image: Nog walking with a cane]

In [DS9: "Soldiers of the Empire"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Soldiers_of_the_Empire_(episode)), Bashir remarks that Martok is partially blind (having lost an eye to the Jem'Hadar while in captivity), and that this is affecting his ability to fight. Martok refuses to adjust his behavior after injuring himself in a holosuite.

[image: Martok's injured eye]

In [VOY: "Year of Hell"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Year_of_Hell_(episode)), Tuvok is blinded by an explosion. He seems to cope using little more than Vulcan mental discipline.

[image: Tuvok shaving with a straight razor while blind]

Comment: TNG: "Loud as a Whisper" features a deaf negotiator who expresses himself telepathicallly through aides, but struggles after he loses them. Not sure this counts as "everyday", given the unusual way he originally compensates, but it's worth a mention. (Edit: Already mentioned in the comments on the question itself, I see. Worth mentioning again though. :-))

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yeah I hesitated to add that one for the reason you describe. Will see how I feel tomorrow regarding including it for completeness's sake.

Comment: If you want to count PTSD, I would suggest Picard's Borgification.  His recovery was the basic premise of an entire episode [Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29).  The idea of lasting repercussions is brought up later, including in ST:First Contact when his ship is ordered to stay away.  Similarly, one could say that Borg involvement has affected Seven of Nine's ability to understand humanity.

Comment: How about Spock going blind in TOS - Operation -- Annihilate!?

Answer (score 12):

DS9 episode "Melora" concerns an Elaysian, named Melora Pazlar. She is confined to a wheelchair so long as she is in "standard" gravity.

[image]

Comment: @MrLister <EmilyLatella>Oh, then.  Nevvvvermind...</Emily>